# Organize Imports shortcut not working after STS update

Tags: spring-tool-suite

After installing the most recent update to STS 3.9.0, my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> keyboard to Organize Imports is no longer working.  The key shortcut exists in Preferences->General->Keys (["Keys" preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZII9.png)) but is missing in the Source menu (["Source" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx63q.png)).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/160). You can workaround it by fixing the Eclipse shortcut keys preferences.

From the bug report:

> here is how you can fix that issue:
>
> Go to the Preferences -> General -> Keys
>       press Filters... and de-select Filter uncategorized commands.
>       Look for the command "Go To Symbol in File" and select that,
>       press unbind and Apply and Close

Comment: After following above steps, the bug doesn't come back. Works fine.

Answer (score 24):

Another way to fix this that survives STS restarts is to go:
Preferences -> General -> Keys 
and change the "When" value to 'Editing Java Source'.

[image: This is how I have my settings and works for me]